# CTE generating "multi-part identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that uses a CTE and it has worked fine. I recently moved to a new server however and now it kicks up an error

> *The multi-part identifier "DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink.categoryID" could not be bound*

I can fix this by changing the compatibility level of the database to 80 (SQL Server 2000) but I'd prefer to fix the problem properly - anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

The stored procedure is:

```
;WITH CTE( CategoryID, ParentCategoryID )
AS
(
    SELECT CategoryID, ParentCategoryID
    FROM DOWNLOADS_fileCategories
    WHERE CategoryID = @startCategoryID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.CategoryID, a.ParentCategoryID
    FROM DOWNLOADS_fileCategories a
    INNER JOIN CTE b ON b.CategoryID = a.ParentCategoryID
)
SELECT CategoryID INTO #tempLinkTable FROM CTE

set @query = 'SELECT TOP ' + cast(@noRecordsToReturn as varchar(5)) + ' DOWNLOADS_files.downloadID, DOWNLOADS_files.fileTypeID, DOWNLOADS_files.downloadName, DOWNLOADS_files.downloadFileName, DOWNLOADS_files.sizeInKb, DOWNLOADS_files.dateAdded, DOWNLOADS_files.visible, SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeName, SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeExtension
FROM DOWNLOADS_files LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_fileTypes ON DOWNLOADS_files.fileTypeID = SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeID INNER JOIN
                  #tempLinkTable ON DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink.categoryID = #tempLinkTable.categoryID
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS_files.dateAdded DESC'

exec(@query)
```

The tables I have are:

**DOWNLOADS_files**

```
downloadID
downloadFileName
```

**DOWNLOADS_fileCategories**

```
categoryID
parentCategoryID
categoryName
```

**DOWNLOADS_fileCategoryLink**

```
categoryID
downloadID
```

Many thanks!

Bob

Comment: BTW in later versions of SQL Server you can use `SELECT TOP(@noRecordsToReturn)` so you don't need dynamic SQL here at all.

Comment: I'm very interested in anything that enables me to simplify the above query - I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.  I've updated my initial post to include the table details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dynamic SQL generates a query like

```
SELECT TOP 10 DOWNLOADS_files.downloadID,
              DOWNLOADS_files.fileTypeID,
              DOWNLOADS_files.downloadName,
              DOWNLOADS_files.downloadFileName,
              DOWNLOADS_files.sizeInKb,
              DOWNLOADS_files.dateAdded,
              DOWNLOADS_files.visible,
              SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeName,
              SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeExtension
FROM   DOWNLOADS_files
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_fileTypes
         ON DOWNLOADS_files.fileTypeID = SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeID
       INNER JOIN #tempLinkTable
         ON DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink.categoryID = #tempLinkTable.categoryID
ORDER  BY DOWNLOADS_files.dateAdded DESC
```

The inner join condition

```
   INNER JOIN #tempLinkTable
     ON DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink.categoryID = #tempLinkTable.categoryID
```

references a table `DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink` that doesn't exist in the query. I'm surprised the query ever worked but maybe there was some parser bug that has since been fixed.

To fix this properly we would need to know what table `categoryID` actually belongs to.

**Edit: Maybe**

```
SELECT TOP (@noRecordsToReturn) DOWNLOADS_files.downloadID,
                                DOWNLOADS_files.fileTypeID,
                                DOWNLOADS_files.downloadName,
                                DOWNLOADS_files.downloadFileName,
                                DOWNLOADS_files.sizeInKb,
                                DOWNLOADS_files.dateAdded,
                                DOWNLOADS_files.visible,
                                SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeName,
                                SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeExtension
FROM   DOWNLOADS_files
       INNER JOIN DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink
         ON DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink.downloadID = DOWNLOADS_files.downloadID
       INNER JOIN #tempLinkTable
         ON DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink.categoryID = #tempLinkTable.categoryID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN SYS_fileTypes
         ON DOWNLOADS_files.fileTypeID = SYS_fileTypes.fileTypeID
ORDER  BY DOWNLOADS_files.dateAdded DESC
```

Comment: Martin, many thanks for your detailed response (and for taking the time to help!), I must admit the query goes beyond my understanding of SQL and I was helped to created it.

The deal is is I have a table that holds a category 'tree' (using parentID>categoryID) and this query returns all the downloads associated with categories below that parent level (the value is passed in the @startCategoryID variable).

In order to allow a 'download' to be in more than one category, downloads are associated with a category via a intermiary table called 'DOWNLOADS_downloadCategoryLink'.

Comment: Wonderful - many thanks Martin, that has worked a treat (and allowed me to do away with the dynamic SQL too!